# How to branch CVS after edits?

Tags: cvs, branching-and-merging, tortoisecvs

I'm struggling to get a hang of branching in CVS after reading the documentation & tutorials online. Let me give you an example of how my dev flow sometimes works:

I'll make a few changes on something (let's say fix some bug that not surprisingly turns into a larger project/activity). Now, I don't want to commit these changes to the main branch because they will be released if someone does an Update on the webserver.

I looked up branching, but if I try and branch these files then it says I can't because the files have been modified. Am I going  about this the wrong way? Up until now I've just left these changes stewing in my local sandbox, but this can get tricky with multiple overlapping projects/bug fixes (some of which are quick and need to be released before the changes mentioned above).

Comment: I found a site that says you can do a "cvs -b" tag which will create a branch from a tag. Is it just because I'm using TortoiseCVS that I can't perform this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was effectively impossible to make this task work. Having finally implemented Git, I have been given wings and no longer do I have to trudge through the mud of CVS. Case closed ... do not attempt branching with CVS (especially after changes).

Answer (score 2):

This can be readily accomplished by unticking *Check that files are unmodified* on the Branch Creation dialogue box.

Once the branch is created, switch to the branch by doing an *Update Special* and choosing the new branch (you may need to click *Update list...* for the new branch to appear). The locally-modified files will be unaffected by this update (provided that you do not tick *Clean copy*). Then simply do a *Commit* as normal to make your changes appear in the new branch.

Comment: Interesting. I'm upvoting so anyone still using CVS can read this.

Comment: @MikeMurko Regrettably being forced to use CVS is the least of my ancient technology concerns, I'm also still expected to use C++98.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with cvs for ten years or so ;)

I think you have to update your working-copy first. This will merge all changes from the main-branch into your working-copy. If this doesn't help just do a fresh checkout into a different directory, branch away and copy your changes into the new workingcopy (but be careful, if someone else changed something in those files, you are overwriting his changes).

Comment: Yes I did do an update to my working copy, but this doesn't let me branch it. I don't know if this is a good solution because it seems to ignore the whole point of source control which is that I shouldn't have to be copy and pasting around and potentially overwriting changes of other developers. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

its absolutely possible to do this, in fact it was one of the design principle of cvs to be able to do this.

> http://cedric.babault.free.fr/TortoiseCVSDoc/UserGuide_en.html#advanced.branching

Comment: At the time I had read that user guide. It still doesn't appear to answer the situation posed in my question. I had several changes to my working directory and wanted to commit them onto a separate branch. Turns out this is *exactly* what git allows you to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not terribly difficult to do:

1. Copy your root cvs directory to a new location
2. Wipe and re-checkout the root from cvs
3. Branch
4. Update to branch
5. Copy the files you've added or changed from the copy back to the main root directory
6. Add Content
7. Commit
8. Enjoy

Edit: it's worth noting that in step 5, be sure NOT to copy any "CVS" folders back

Comment: "Not terribly difficult"? You have to recheckout the entire repository. That is an incredible amount of work compared to using git and: branch, commit, switch back to original branch.